# Odoo 14: Domain filter in a One2many field second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I had this code in Odoo 12 and running fine once we migrated to Odoo 14 gives an error when clicking the Roles field.

Code Error

```
Traceback:
Error: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array
```

First View
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDaCY.png)

Stacktrace
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Gcm.png)

the field role is being populated like this:

View:

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="product_pricelist_item_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">product.pricelist.item.inherit</field>
      <field name="model">product.pricelist.item</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_pricelist_item_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">

       <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_tmpl_id']" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="string">Roles</attribute>
       <attribute name="domain">"[('is_employee','=', True)]"</attribute>

    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

variables in model:

```
item_ids = fields.One2many('product.pricelist.item', 'pricelist_id', 'Pricelist Items',copy=True, default=False)
    
is_employee = fields.Boolean(string='Is an Employee', default=True)
```

Is there syntax updates for Odoo 14?

Comment: it would be great if you add some code snippet in your question. Like how you populate `role` field through python?

Comment: thank you for your response sorry i new to posting questions in stack, added the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we apply domain using attributes in xml side, it should be list style instead of double quotes. For example

> ```
> <attribute name="domain">[('is_employee','=', True)]</attribute>
> ```

And don't forget to close xpath tag. I cannot see it in your question.